# get exact value of a column with multiple datatype in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with date(YYYYMMDD), int and float values in a csv file, and i want to store all as varchar in table,but when trying to convert with pandas dataframe i am getting a .0 appended at last even when i am casting the column to string.

**test.csv**

| Node | Parent |
| --- | --- |
| 19 | 2.3 |
| 20 | 20220616 |
| 13 | 12 |
| 15 | 39.19 |

python code i am trying:

```
import pandas as pd

z=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
z['Parent']=z['Parent'].astype(str)
print(z)
```

output i am getting is :

|  | Node | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 19 | 2.3 |
| 1 | 20 | 20220616.0 |
| 2 | 13 | 12.0 |
| 3 | 15 | 39.19 |

Output i want:

|  | Node | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 19 | 2.3 |
| 1 | 20 | 20220616 |
| 2 | 13 | 12 |
| 3 | 15 | 39.19 |

Comment: `z=pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype='str')`?

Comment: @Quang haong yes thanks this is working, but do you know why casting is not working?

Comment: @TomatoMaster pandas assumed it was a float column, so it formatted it that way.

Comment: and can we apply dtype='str' for only specific column?

Comment: Yes, using the following format `dtype = {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’}`

Answer (score 1):

you can read them as string to avoid being treated as floats

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\mni\stackoverflow\temp.csv', dtype=str)
```

```
    Node    Parent
0   19      2.3
1   20      20220616
2   13      12
3   15      39.19
```

Comment: Can we do this directly to the dataframe, because just for sample i have provided here the pd.read_csv('test.csv'), in my case i am directly getting the dataframe from an api